# Is there a more succinct Linq expression for inserting a constant between every item in a list?

Tags: c#, linq

Here's what I have at the moment:

```
public List<double> GetStrokeDashArray(List<double> dashLengths, double gap)
{
    return dashLengths
        .SelectMany(dl => new[] { dl, gap })
        .Take(dashLengths.Count * 2 - 1)
        .ToList();
}
```

Results for `GetStrokeDashArray(new List<double> { 2, 4, 7, 11, 16 }, 2);`

```
2, 2, 4, 2, 7, 2, 11, 2, 16
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the best way is to create a specific extension method for that:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Intersperse<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T value)
{
    bool first = true;
    foreach(T item in source)
    {
        if (!first) yield return value;
        yield return item;
        first = false;
    }
}
```

You can then write your method as follows:

```
public List<double> GetStrokeDashArray(List<double> dashLengths, double gap)
{
    return dashLengths
        .Intersperse(gap)
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: +1 for the answer, and for naming the method `Intersperse()` :)

Comment: @DanM, is that a funny name? I thought it was the right word, but English is not my native language so perhaps I'm mistaken ;)

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that it was funny, it's actually the perfect word. Sometimes it's hard to come up with the right word, but you nailed it.

Comment: I'm marking this answer (but might change my mind if someone actually comes up with a native Linq expression that's more succinct than mine). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an iterator block instead:

```
IEnumerable<Double> GetStrokeDashArray(IEnumerable<Double> dashLengths, Double gap) {
  using (var enumerator = dashLengths.GetEnumerator()) {
    if (enumerator.MoveNext())
      yield return enumerator.Current;
    while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
      yield return gap;
      yield return enumerator.Current;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for using the enumerator explicitly, it's slightly more efficient than my answer... but you should `Dispose` the enumerator when you're done ;)

Comment: +1 for interesting solution, but it's not technically Linq, and it's not reusable for other purposes (in its current form), so I'm going to with Thomas's answer.

Comment: @DanM: Well, you just have to replace `Double` with `T`, make it an extension method and rename it like Thomas did. But he already gave that answer. :-D

Answer (score 1):

This is best I could come up with for the `Zip` method:

```
var gaps = Enumerable.Repeat(gap, dashLengths.Count - 1);
return dashLengths.Take(1)
    .Concat(gaps.Zip(dashLengths.Skip(1), (x, y) => new[] {x, y})
                .SelectMany(x => x))
    .ToList();
```

Less succinct... but uses `Zip`.